# Table row no page break when exporting to PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf

Table row is not making page break when table is exported to PDF. I've tried to make page break on each table row with:

```
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
```

Table row breaks like this (export to PDF - view inside browser):

[image]

I would like table row 'Vrsta blaga/storitve' to stay compact. So, cells are not displayed in non-printable areas, like in the picture above.  Is this possible? What styling should I use? Here is my code:

```html
<style>#tblArticles{font-size: 12px !important; font-family: verdana, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;}
#tblArticles td{border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;}
#tblArticles th {border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;background-color: #dddddd;}
</style>
<style>#tblLeft{position:absolute;left:0; font-size: 10px !important; font-family: verdana, sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse; width:40%;}
#tblLeft td{font-size: 10px !important; border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;}
#tblLeft th {font-size: 10px !important; border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;background-color: #dddddd;}</style>
<style>#tblRight{position:absolute;right:0; font-size: 10px !important; font-family: verdana, sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse; width:20%;}
#tblRight td{font-size: 10px !important; text-align: center;padding: 8px;}</style>
<table id='tblArticles'>
<thead>
<th>Vrsta blaga/storitve</th>
                                <th>Interna številka</th>
                                <th>Prodana koda</th>
                                <th>Količina</th>
                                <th>EnM</th>
                                <th>Cena brez DDV</th>
                                <th>Vrednost brez DDV</th>
                                <th>DDV</th>
                                <th>Znesek DDV</th>
                                <th>Vrednost z DDV</th>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
<tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
<tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td rowspan='2'><label>Mali kuharski mojster</label></td>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VFdNNE5TIE1L.jpg><br/>
<label>VFdNNE5TIE1L</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>2,00</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>KOM</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>32,21 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>64,42 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>22,00 %</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>14,17 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>78,59 €</td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VjJUOEVaIE1L.jpg><br/>
<label>VjJUOEVaIE1L</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td rowspan='12'><label>Veliki kuharski mojster</label></td>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/NFA1SFFKVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>NFA1SFFKVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='12'>12,00</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='12'>KOM</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='12'>65,69 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='12'>788,28 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='12'>22,00 %</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='12'>173,42 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='12'>961,70 €</td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/RzZHOFo1Vks=.jpg><br/>
<label>RzZHOFo1Vks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VUhHOVVZVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>VUhHOVVZVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VThWUTdLVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>VThWUTdLVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/R05YQlNDVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>R05YQlNDVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OVQyU1c3Vks=.jpg><br/>
<label>OVQyU1c3Vks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TTlHUkVOVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>TTlHUkVOVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OUtSNUQ2Vks=.jpg><br/>
<label>OUtSNUQ2Vks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OENQMkNaVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>OENQMkNaVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/Q1o2Qjc3Vks=.jpg><br/>
<label>Q1o2Qjc3Vks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/V0xNOVJBVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>V0xNOVJBVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TjRMOVdBVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>TjRMOVdBVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td rowspan='2'><label>Večerja na zajli</label></td>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/Rk5SRFdWVlo=.jpg><br/>
<label>Rk5SRFdWVlo=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>2,00</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>KOM</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>91,56 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>183,12 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>22,00 %</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>40,29 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>223,41 €</td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OEI4V0FSVlo=.jpg><br/>
<label>OEI4V0FSVlo=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td rowspan='10'><label>Za moške, ki mislijo da kosilo pade z neba</label></td>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VVpETFhUWk0=.jpg><br/>
<label>VVpETFhUWk0=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='10'>10,00</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='10'>KOM</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='10'>32,34 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='10'>323,40 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='10'>22,00 %</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='10'>71,15 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='10'>394,55 €</td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OUJXREo5Wk0=.jpg><br/>
<label>OUJXREo5Wk0=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TlA4OVU1Wk0=.jpg><br/>
<label>TlA4OVU1Wk0=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/NlRTOFRQWk0=.jpg><br/>
<label>NlRTOFRQWk0=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VVRQVTRSWk0=.jpg><br/>
<label>VVRQVTRSWk0=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/WEEzUzZCWk0=.jpg><br/>
<label>WEEzUzZCWk0=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TVZWUkVNWk0=.jpg><br/>
<label>TVZWUkVNWk0=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/RDlGVTVOWk0=.jpg><br/>
<label>RDlGVTVOWk0=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TFBBR1pTWk0=.jpg><br/>
<label>TFBBR1pTWk0=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<td>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/QkVYQ1ZKWk0=.jpg><br/>
<label>QkVYQ1ZKWk0=</label><br/>
</td>
<td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table><br/>
<div style='page-break-inside:avoid;margin-bottom: 30px;'>
<label style='position:relative;left:0;font-size:12px;'>Specifikacija obračunanega davka, dokumenta št.:</label><br/>
<div id='divBottom' style='position:relative;width:100%;min-height:160px;'>
<table id='tblLeft'>
<th>Stopnja</th><th>Osnova za DDV</th><th>Znesek DDV</th><th>Vrednost z DDV</th>
<tr>
<td>9,5 %</td><td>0,00 €</td><td>0,00 €</td><td>0,00 €</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>22 %</td><td>1359,22 €</td><td>299,03 €</td><td>1658,25 €</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id='tblRight'>
<tr style='border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='text-align:left;'><b>Skupaj brez DDV:</b></td><td style='text-align:right;'>1359,22 €</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align:left;'><b>Osnova za DDV</b></td><td style='text-align:right;'>1359,22 €</td>
</tr>
<tr style='border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='text-align:left;'><b>DDV:</b></td><td style='text-align:right;'>299,03 €</td>
</tr>
</table>
<label style='position:absolute;right:80px;bottom:20px;'><b>SKUPAJ:</b></label>
<label style='position:absolute;right:0;bottom:20px;'><b>1658,25 €</b></label>
</div></div><br/><br/><br/>
```

Comment: where do you want page break exactly? Each set should not be carried to the next page, otherwise they can follow on after the other? is that what you are asking for?

Comment: I don't want table row to end up at the bottom at the page. I want break at each row. So, each row is compact or displayed on another page.

Comment: each row or each row in Vrsta blaga/storitve column?

Comment: Each row in Vrsta blaga/storitve. Thanks for this tip.

Comment: see if https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dompdf/AEc8OT2YGYo helps..

Comment: Added solution, feel free to use it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `page-break-inside:avoid;`, But the bug arises from a visual mindset!

We think when using `rowspan` there is only one row in the structure of the table, while its not ture. Rows architecture remain as is, only hidden. And its why you thought it is breaking inside when printing, while the fact is `page-break-inside:avoid;` is working fine & only some borders are hidden.

Even though you can continue with `page-break-inside:avoid;` in new design, but its better to force separation by breaking after before/after row [`page-break-before`].

So, Change your table design from `rowspan` methodology, to `inner/nested tables`, then Remove all inline `page-break` rules & just add this in the `<style>...</style>`:

```
#tblArticles tr{
   page-break-before: always;
}
```

```css
            #tblArticles{
                font-size: 12px !important;
                font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
            }
            #tblArticles tr{
                page-break-before: always;
            }
            #tblArticles td{
                border: 1px solid black;
                text-align: center;
                /*padding: 8px;*/
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
               
            }
            #tblArticles table.inner{
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
            #tblArticles table.inner td{
                padding: 0;
                width: 50%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
            }
             #tblArticles table.inner tr td{
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            }
            #tblArticles table.inner tr:last-child td{
                border-bottom: none;
            }
            #tblArticles th {
                border: 1px solid black;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 8px;
                background-color: #dddddd;
            }
            #tblLeft{
                position:absolute;
                left:0;
                font-size: 10px !important;
                font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
                border-collapse:collapse;
                width:40%;
            }
            #tblLeft td{
                font-size: 10px !important;
                border: 1px solid black;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 8px;
            }
            #tblLeft th {
                font-size: 10px !important; 
                border: 1px solid black;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 8px;
                background-color: #dddddd;
            }
            #tblRight{
                position:absolute;
                right:0;
                font-size: 10px !important; 
                font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
                border-collapse:collapse; 
                width:20%;
            }
            #tblRight td{
                font-size: 10px !important; 
                text-align: center;
                padding: 8px;
            }
```

```html
        <table id='tblArticles'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Vrsta blaga/storitve</th>
                    <th>Interna številka</th>
                    <th>Prodana koda</th>
                    <th>Količina</th>
                    <th>EnM</th>
                    <th>Cena brez DDV</th>
                    <th>Vrednost brez DDV</th>
                    <th>DDV</th>
                    <th>Znesek DDV</th>
                    <th>Vrednost z DDV</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
                <tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
                <tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
                <tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
                <tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
                <tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
                <tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
                <tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
                <tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
                <tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Mali kuharski mojster</label></td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <table class="inner">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VFdNNE5TIE1L.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>VFdNNE5TIE1L</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VjJUOEVaIE1L.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>VjJUOEVaIE1L</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>2,00</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>KOM</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>32,21 €</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>64,42 €</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>22,00 %</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>14,17 €</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>78,59 €</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Veliki kuharski mojster</label></td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <table  class="inner">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/NFA1SFFKVks=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>NFA1SFFKVks=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/RzZHOFo1Vks=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>RzZHOFo1Vks=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VUhHOVVZVks=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>VUhHOVVZVks=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VThWUTdLVks=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>VThWUTdLVks=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/R05YQlNDVks=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>R05YQlNDVks=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OVQyU1c3Vks=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>OVQyU1c3Vks=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TTlHUkVOVks=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>TTlHUkVOVks=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OUtSNUQ2Vks=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>OUtSNUQ2Vks=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OENQMkNaVks=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>OENQMkNaVks=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/Q1o2Qjc3Vks=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>Q1o2Qjc3Vks=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/V0xNOVJBVks=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>V0xNOVJBVks=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TjRMOVdBVks=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>TjRMOVdBVks=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>12,00</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>KOM</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>65,69 €</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>788,28 €</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>22,00 %</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>173,42 €</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>961,70 €</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Večerja na zajli</label></td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <table class="inner">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/Rk5SRFdWVlo=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>Rk5SRFdWVlo=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OEI4V0FSVlo=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>OEI4V0FSVlo=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>2,00</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>KOM</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>91,56 €</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>183,12 €</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>22,00 %</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>40,29 €</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>223,41 €</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Za moške, ki mislijo da kosilo pade z neba</label></td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <table class="inner">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VVpETFhUWk0=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>VVpETFhUWk0=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OUJXREo5Wk0=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>OUJXREo5Wk0=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TlA4OVU1Wk0=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>TlA4OVU1Wk0=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/NlRTOFRQWk0=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>NlRTOFRQWk0=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VVRQVTRSWk0=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>VVRQVTRSWk0=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/WEEzUzZCWk0=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>WEEzUzZCWk0=</label>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TVZWUkVNWk0=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>TVZWUkVNWk0=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/RDlGVTVOWk0=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>RDlGVTVOWk0=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TFBBR1pTWk0=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>TFBBR1pTWk0=</label><br/>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/QkVYQ1ZKWk0=.jpg" /><br/>
                                    <label>QkVYQ1ZKWk0=</label>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>10,00</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>KOM</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>32,34 €</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>323,40 €</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>22,00 %</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>71,15 €</td>
                    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>394,55 €</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <div style='page-break-inside:avoid;margin-bottom: 30px;'>
            <label style='position:relative;left:0;font-size:12px;'>Specifikacija obračunanega davka, dokumenta št.:</label><br/>
            <div id='divBottom' style='position:relative;width:100%;min-height:160px;'>
                <table id='tblLeft'>
                    <th>Stopnja</th><th>Osnova za DDV</th><th>Znesek DDV</th><th>Vrednost z DDV</th>
                    <tr>
                        <td>9,5 %</td><td>0,00 €</td><td>0,00 €</td><td>0,00 €</td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td>22 %</td><td>1359,22 €</td><td>299,03 €</td><td>1658,25 €</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table id='tblRight'>
                    <tr style='border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
                        <td style='text-align:left;'><b>Skupaj brez DDV:</b></td><td style='text-align:right;'>1359,22 €</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style='text-align:left;'><b>Osnova za DDV</b></td><td style='text-align:right;'>1359,22 €</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style='border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
                        <td style='text-align:left;'><b>DDV:</b></td><td style='text-align:right;'>299,03 €</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <label style='position:absolute;right:80px;bottom:20px;'><b>SKUPAJ:</b></label>
                <label style='position:absolute;right:0;bottom:20px;'><b>1658,25 €</b></label>
            </div></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to delete edges around inner td? (checkbox and barcode)

Comment: Yeah. sure it is

Comment: @FrenkyB. In order to remove redundant annoying borders of inner table, I just added `border:0` to `#tblArticles table.inner td` & applied the border only to first row's bottom line.( using this: `#tblArticles table.inner tr:first-child  td{ border-bottom: 1px solid black; }` )

Comment: @FrenkyB. Another update applied on snippet. replaced `#tblArticles table.inner tr:first-child td{ border-bottom: 1px solid black; }` with `#tblArticles table.inner tr td{ border-bottom: 1px solid black; }` and `#tblArticles table.inner tr:last-child td{ border-bottom: none; }` to make it include mega-rows with more than only 2 sub-rows in inner table.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Can I please ask you (it's a bounty) to look into my another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479862/export-html-to-pdf-always-align-at-the-bottom-of-a-new-page

Comment: Behrad if you find time to check also the case, when there are more items in the row than page size: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6799351/vecerja_na_zajli.png. Is it possible also to break on page cell, so it's not overlapping the next page?

Comment: Sure Dude. @FrenkyB There is no need for bounty. We are all here for sharing what we know.

Comment: @FrenkyB I just posted the answer for your other question. But about the snapshot you've shared, as a rule of thump please test adding these 5 rules inside a `@media print {...}`for the case. Hope it helps: `table{ page-break-after:auto }` , 
  `tr{ page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }` , 
`td{ page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }` , 
  `thead{ display:table-header-group }` and 
`tfoot{ display:table-footer-group }`

Comment: It is still the same. Did I put @media print at the right place? Here is latest example: http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/yMbabz?editors=1000

Answer (score 2):

there is nothing wrong with `page-break-inside`

it table should be like the following to work for `page-break-inside`

```
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
 <td ><label>Mali kuharski mojster</label></td>
 <td class="td">
    <table >
        <tbody>
            <tr> 
                <td>
                    <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VFdNNE5TIE1L.jpg><br/>
                    <label>VFdNNE5TIE1L</label><br/>
                </td>   
                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
            </tr>       
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VjJUOEVaIE1L.jpg><br/>
                    <label>VjJUOEVaIE1L</label><br/>
                </td>
                <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>            
 </td>
 <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >2,00</td>
 <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >KOM</td>
 <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >32,21 €</td>
 <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >64,42 €</td>
 <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >22,00 %</td>
 <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >14,17 €</td>
 <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >78,59 €</td>
```

instead of

```
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
    <td rowspan='2'><label>Mali kuharski mojster</label></td>
    <td>
        <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VFdNNE5TIE1L.jpg><br/>
        <label>VFdNNE5TIE1L</label><br/>
    </td>
    <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>2,00</td>
    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>KOM</td>
    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>32,21 €</td>
    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>64,42 €</td>
    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>22,00 %</td>
    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>14,17 €</td>
    <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='2'>78,59 €</td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
    <td>
        <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VjJUOEVaIE1L.jpg><br/>
        <label>VjJUOEVaIE1L</label><br/>
    </td>
    <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
```

Restructure the entire html

```
<style>#tblArticles{font-size: 12px !important; font-family: verdana, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;}
   #tblArticles td{border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;}
   #tblArticles th {border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;background-color: #dddddd;}
</style>
<style>#tblLeft{position:absolute;left:0; font-size: 10px !important; font-family: verdana, sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse; width:40%;}
   #tblLeft td{font-size: 10px !important; border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;}
   #tblLeft th {font-size: 10px !important; border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;background-color: #dddddd;}
</style>
<style>#tblRight{position:absolute;right:0; font-size: 10px !important; font-family: verdana, sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse; width:20%;}
   #tblRight td{font-size: 10px !important; text-align: center;padding: 8px;}
</style>
<style>
    #tblArticles td.td{
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #tblArticles td.td table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #tblArticles td.td table td{
        border: 0px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }


    #tblArticles td.td table tr:last-child td{
        border-bottom: 0px;
        border-top: 0px;
    }

    #tblArticles th.th {
        padding: 0px;   
    }

    #tblArticles th.th table {  
        padding: 0px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #tblArticles th.th table th{
        border: 0px;
    }

    #tblArticles th.th table th:first-child{
        width: 70%;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }

    #tblArticles td.td table tr td:first-child{
        width: 70%;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
<table id='tblArticles'>
   <thead>
      <th>Vrsta blaga/storitve</th>
      <th class="th"><table><thead><th>Interna številka</th><th>Prodana koda</th></thead></table></th>
      <th>Količina</th>
      <th>EnM</th>
      <th>Cena brez DDV</th>
      <th>Vrednost brez DDV</th>
      <th>DDV</th>
      <th>Znesek DDV</th>
      <th>Vrednost z DDV</th>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
      <tr style='visibility:hidden;'>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style='visibility:hidden;'>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style='visibility:hidden;'>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
   <tbody style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
      <tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
         <td ><label>Mali kuharski mojster</label></td>
         <td class="td">
            <table >
                <tbody>
                    <tr> 
                        <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VFdNNE5TIE1L.jpg><br/>
                            <label>VFdNNE5TIE1L</label><br/>
                        </td>   
                        <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                    </tr>       
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VjJUOEVaIE1L.jpg><br/>
                            <label>VjJUOEVaIE1L</label><br/>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>            
         </td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >2,00</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >KOM</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >32,21 €</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >64,42 €</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >22,00 %</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >14,17 €</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >78,59 €</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
         <td ><label>Veliki kuharski mojster</label></td>
         <td class="td">
            <table >
                <tbody>
                    <tr> 
                        <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/NFA1SFFKVks=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>NFA1SFFKVks=</label><br/>
                        </td>   
                        <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                    </tr>       
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/RzZHOFo1Vks=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>RzZHOFo1Vks=</label><br/>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VUhHOVVZVks=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>VUhHOVVZVks=</label><br/>
                         </td>
                         <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr >
                         <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VThWUTdLVks=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>VThWUTdLVks=</label><br/>
                         </td>
                         <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                         <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VThWUTdLVks=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>VThWUTdLVks=</label><br/>
                         </td>
                         <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                         <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/R05YQlNDVks=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>R05YQlNDVks=</label><br/>
                         </td>
                         <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                         <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OVQyU1c3Vks=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>OVQyU1c3Vks=</label><br/>
                         </td>
                         <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                      </tr>
                    <tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
                         <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TTlHUkVOVks=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>TTlHUkVOVks=</label><br/>
                         </td>
                         <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
                         <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OUtSNUQ2Vks=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>OUtSNUQ2Vks=</label><br/>
                         </td>
                         <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
                         <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OENQMkNaVks=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>OENQMkNaVks=</label><br/>
                         </td>
                         <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
                         <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/Q1o2Qjc3Vks=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>Q1o2Qjc3Vks=</label><br/>
                         </td>
                         <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
                         <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/V0xNOVJBVks=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>V0xNOVJBVks=</label><br/>
                         </td>
                         <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
                         <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TjRMOVdBVks=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>TjRMOVdBVks=</label><br/>
                         </td>
                         <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                      </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>            
         </td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >12,00</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >KOM</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >65,69 €</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >788,28 €</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >22,00 %</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >173,42 €</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >961,70 €</td>
      </tr>





      <tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
         <td ><label>Večerja na zajli</label></td>
         <td class="td">
            <table >
                <tbody>
                    <tr> 
                        <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/Rk5SRFdWVlo=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>Rk5SRFdWVlo=</label><br/>
                        </td>   
                        <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                    </tr>       
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OEI4V0FSVlo=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>OEI4V0FSVlo=</label><br/>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>            
         </td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >2,00</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >KOM</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >91,56 €</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >183,12 €</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >22,00 %</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >40,29 €</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >223,41 €</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
         <td ><label>Za moške, ki mislijo da kosilo pade z neba</label></td>
         <td class="td">
            <table >
                <tbody>
                    <tr> 
                        <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VVpETFhUWk0=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>VVpETFhUWk0=</label><br/>
                        </td>   
                        <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                    </tr>       
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OUJXREo5Wk0=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>OUJXREo5Wk0=</label><br/>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                         <td>
                            <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TlA4OVU1Wk0=.jpg><br/>
                            <label>TlA4OVU1Wk0=</label><br/>
                         </td>
                         <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                    </tr>   
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TlA4OVU1Wk0=.jpg><br/>
                        <label>TlA4OVU1Wk0=</label><br/>
                     </td>
                     <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                  </tr>         
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/NlRTOFRQWk0=.jpg><br/>
                        <label>NlRTOFRQWk0=</label><br/>
                     </td>
                     <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                  </tr>         

                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VVRQVTRSWk0=.jpg><br/>
                        <label>VVRQVTRSWk0=</label><br/>
                     </td>
                     <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/WEEzUzZCWk0=.jpg><br/>
                        <label>WEEzUzZCWk0=</label><br/>
                     </td>
                     <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TVZWUkVNWk0=.jpg><br/>
                        <label>TVZWUkVNWk0=</label><br/>
                     </td>
                     <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/RDlGVTVOWk0=.jpg><br/>
                        <label>RDlGVTVOWk0=</label><br/>
                     </td>
                     <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TFBBR1pTWk0=.jpg><br/>
                        <label>TFBBR1pTWk0=</label><br/>
                     </td>
                     <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/QkVYQ1ZKWk0=.jpg><br/>
                        <label>QkVYQ1ZKWk0=</label><br/>
                     </td>
                     <td><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
                  </tr>               
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >10,00</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >KOM</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >32,34 €</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >323,40 €</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >22,00 %</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >71,15 €</td>
         <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' >394,55 €</td>
      </tr>



   </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<div style='page-break-inside:avoid;margin-bottom: 30px;'>
   <label style='position:relative;left:0;font-size:12px;'>Specifikacija obračunanega davka, dokumenta št.:</label><br/>
   <div id='divBottom' style='position:relative;width:100%;min-height:160px;'>
      <table id='tblLeft'>
         <th>Stopnja</th>
         <th>Osnova za DDV</th>
         <th>Znesek DDV</th>
         <th>Vrednost z DDV</th>
         <tr>
            <td>9,5 %</td>
            <td>0,00 €</td>
            <td>0,00 €</td>
            <td>0,00 €</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>22 %</td>
            <td>1359,22 €</td>
            <td>299,03 €</td>
            <td>1658,25 €</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table id='tblRight'>
         <tr style='border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
            <td style='text-align:left;'><b>Skupaj brez DDV:</b></td>
            <td style='text-align:right;'>1359,22 €</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style='text-align:left;'><b>Osnova za DDV</b></td>
            <td style='text-align:right;'>1359,22 €</td>
         </tr>
         <tr style='border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
            <td style='text-align:left;'><b>DDV:</b></td>
            <td style='text-align:right;'>299,03 €</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <label style='position:absolute;right:80px;bottom:20px;'><b>SKUPAJ:</b></label>
      <label style='position:absolute;right:0;bottom:20px;'><b>1658,25 €</b></label>
   </div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>
```

It not entire solution, it gives you an idea, there are still css issues

Comment: Perhaps you have any working example? this seems a little strange to me - where are table cells written? Please if you can provide working example.

Comment: I am asking just because last row that you wrote is outside table structure.

Comment: I was just giving you an example with last row, I soon as I get time I will update your html, I will put it over here