# Export HTML to PDF always align at the bottom of a new page

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with export html to PDF. I would like section at the bottom to be always aligned at the bottom of a new page.

Right now this section (when it comes to page break) is aligned at the top of a new page:

[image]

Code for that section:

```html
<div style='page-break-inside:avoid;vertical-align:bottom;'>
<font face="Verdana"  >
<br>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:900px;">
          <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td style="width:500px">
     BLAGO DOSTAVIL:&nbsp;______________________<br/><br/>
     Podpis<br/><br/>
     Datum:&nbsp;______________________
    </td>
    <td>
     BLAGO PREVZEL:&nbsp;______________________<br/><br/>
     Podpis<br/><br/>
     Datum:&nbsp;______________________
    </td>
    
   </tr>
    </tbody>
        </table>
</font>
<font face="Verdana" size="1"  >
<br /><br />
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:900px;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:center">
    <i>
     testting d.o.o., testing, ID za DDV: testing, matična št.: testing
     <br>
     tel: +386 XXXXXXXXXX, fax: +386 1 XXXXXXXXX, e-mail: info@XXXX.si, web: www.xxxxxxx.si
     <br>
     Družba je vpisana pri okrožnem sodišču v Ljubljani, št. vpisa v registru: 1/XXXXX/00, ustanovni kapital: XX.000 EUR
     <br>
     Račun odprt pri NLB d.d., Iban: SIXXXXXXX, SWIFT-BIC: LJBASI2X
    </i>
              </td>
            </tr>

   </tbody>
        </table>
</font> 
</div>
```

Here is my code for the whole page (including section at the bottom which jumps into new page at page break):

```html
<style>#tblArticles{font-size: 12px !important; font-family: verdana, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;}
#tblArticles td{border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;}
#tblArticles th {border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;background-color: #dddddd;}
</style>
<style>#tblLeft{position:absolute;left:0; font-size: 10px !important; font-family: verdana, sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse; width:40%;}
#tblLeft td{font-size: 10px !important; border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;}
#tblLeft th {font-size: 10px !important; border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;background-color: #dddddd;}</style>
<style>#tblRight{position:absolute;right:0; font-size: 10px !important; font-family: verdana, sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse; width:20%;}
#tblRight td{font-size: 10px !important; text-align: center;padding: 8px;}</style>
<table id='tblArticles'>
<thead>
<th>Vrsta blaga/storitve</th>
                                <th>Interna številka</th>
                                <th>Prodana koda</th>
                                <th>Količina</th>
                                <th>EnM</th>
                                <th>Cena brez DDV</th>
                                <th>Vrednost brez DDV</th>
                                <th>DDV</th>
                                <th>Znesek DDV</th>
                                <th>Vrednost z DDV</th>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
<tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
<tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td rowspan='1' style='page-break-inside:avoid;'><label>Večerja na zajli</label></td>
<td style=''>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VzlSSlNYVlo=.jpg><br/>
<label>VzlSSlNYVlo=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style=''><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>1,00</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>KOM</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>91,14 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>91,14 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>9,50 %</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>8,66 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>99,80 €</td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td rowspan='7' style='page-break-inside:avoid;'><label>Veliki kuharski mojster</label></td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TDZKVzRDVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>TDZKVzRDVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>7,00</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>KOM</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>65,69 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>459,83 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>22,00 %</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>101,16 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>560,99 €</td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/Q0U2RURCVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>Q0U2RURCVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/RFg0TVZXVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>RFg0TVZXVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OFdGRTJLVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>OFdGRTJLVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/QlROR0NMVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>QlROR0NMVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/SjNYWkJOVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>SjNYWkJOVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style=''>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/M0RFWURXVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>M0RFWURXVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style=''><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table><br/>
<div style='page-break-inside:avoid;margin-bottom: 30px;'>
<label style='position:relative;left:0;font-size:12px;'>Specifikacija obračunanega davka, dokumenta št.:</label><br/>
<div id='divBottom' style='position:relative;width:100%;min-height:160px;'>
<table id='tblLeft'>
<th>Stopnja</th><th>Osnova za DDV</th><th>Znesek DDV</th><th>Vrednost z DDV</th>
<tr>
<td>9,5 %</td><td>91,14 €</td><td>8,66 €</td><td>99,80 €</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>22 %</td><td>459,83 €</td><td>101,16 €</td><td>560,99 €</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id='tblRight'>
<tr style='border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='text-align:left;'><b>Skupaj brez DDV:</b></td><td style='text-align:right;'>550,97 €</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align:left;'><b>Osnova za DDV</b></td><td style='text-align:right;'>550,97 €</td>
</tr>
<tr style='border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='text-align:left;'><b>DDV:</b></td><td style='text-align:right;'>109,82 €</td>
</tr>
</table>
<label style='position:absolute;right:80px;bottom:20px;'><b>SKUPAJ:</b></label>
<label style='position:absolute;right:0;bottom:20px;'><b>660,79 €</b></label>
</div></div><br/><br/><br/>

<div style='page-break-inside:avoid;vertical-align:bottom;'>
<font face="Verdana"  >
<br>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:900px;">
          <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td style="width:500px">
     BLAGO DOSTAVIL:&nbsp;______________________<br/><br/>
     Podpis<br/><br/>
     Datum:&nbsp;______________________
    </td>
    <td>
     BLAGO PREVZEL:&nbsp;______________________<br/><br/>
     Podpis<br/><br/>
     Datum:&nbsp;______________________
    </td>
    
   </tr>
    </tbody>
        </table>
</font>
<font face="Verdana" size="1"  >
<br /><br />
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:900px;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:center">
    <i>
     testting d.o.o., testing, ID za DDV: testing, matična št.: testing
     <br>
     tel: +386 XXXXXXXXXX, fax: +386 1 XXXXXXXXX, e-mail: info@XXXX.si, web: www.xxxxxxx.si
     <br>
     Družba je vpisana pri okrožnem sodišču v Ljubljani, št. vpisa v registru: 1/XXXXX/00, ustanovni kapital: XX.000 EUR
     <br>
     Račun odprt pri NLB d.d., Iban: SIXXXXXXX, SWIFT-BIC: LJBASI2X
    </i>
              </td>
            </tr>

   </tbody>
        </table>
</font> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

I just moved the table holding contact info at the bottom of the page as a new:

```
<tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
```

to the table we are going to stick it to the bottom of the page while printing.

Then you need to only add a style rule for `@media print`, like this:

```
@media print{
  table#stickToFooter{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Say, I didn't manipulate you code in other parts, but just as a `best-practice` rule, please try to avoid surrounding none-inline level elements in inline tags. I mean it'd be much better if you set table's font-family & size using these styling elements:

```
table{
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px
}
```

than enclosing it inside a `<font face="Verdana" size="1">...</font>` tag. Thanks in advance.

```html
<style>#tblArticles{font-size: 12px !important; font-family: verdana, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;}
#tblArticles td{border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;}
#tblArticles th {border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;background-color: #dddddd;}
</style>
<style>#tblLeft{position:absolute;left:0; font-size: 10px !important; font-family: verdana, sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse; width:40%;}
#tblLeft td{font-size: 10px !important; border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;}
#tblLeft th {font-size: 10px !important; border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;background-color: #dddddd;}</style>
<style>#tblRight{position:absolute;right:0; font-size: 10px !important; font-family: verdana, sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse; width:20%;}
#tblRight td{font-size: 10px !important; text-align: center;padding: 8px;}</style>
<style>
        @media print{
            table#stickToFooter{
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
            }
        }
</style>
<table id='tblArticles'>
<thead>
<th>Vrsta blaga/storitve</th>
                                <th>Interna številka</th>
                                <th>Prodana koda</th>
                                <th>Količina</th>
                                <th>EnM</th>
                                <th>Cena brez DDV</th>
                                <th>Vrednost brez DDV</th>
                                <th>DDV</th>
                                <th>Znesek DDV</th>
                                <th>Vrednost z DDV</th>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
<tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
<tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td rowspan='1' style='page-break-inside:avoid;'><label>Večerja na zajli</label></td>
<td style=''>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VzlSSlNYVlo=.jpg><br/>
<label>VzlSSlNYVlo=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style=''><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>1,00</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>KOM</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>91,14 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>91,14 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>9,50 %</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>8,66 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>99,80 €</td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td rowspan='7' style='page-break-inside:avoid;'><label>Veliki kuharski mojster</label></td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TDZKVzRDVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>TDZKVzRDVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>7,00</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>KOM</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>65,69 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>459,83 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>22,00 %</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>101,16 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>560,99 €</td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/Q0U2RURCVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>Q0U2RURCVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/RFg0TVZXVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>RFg0TVZXVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OFdGRTJLVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>OFdGRTJLVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/QlROR0NMVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>QlROR0NMVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/SjNYWkJOVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>SjNYWkJOVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style=''>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/M0RFWURXVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>M0RFWURXVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style=''><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table><br/>
<div style='page-break-inside:avoid;margin-bottom: 30px;'>
<label style='position:relative;left:0;font-size:12px;'>Specifikacija obračunanega davka, dokumenta št.:</label><br/>
<div id='divBottom' style='position:relative;width:100%;min-height:160px;'>
<table id='tblLeft'>
<th>Stopnja</th><th>Osnova za DDV</th><th>Znesek DDV</th><th>Vrednost z DDV</th>
<tr>
<td>9,5 %</td><td>91,14 €</td><td>8,66 €</td><td>99,80 €</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>22 %</td><td>459,83 €</td><td>101,16 €</td><td>560,99 €</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id='tblRight'>
<tr style='border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='text-align:left;'><b>Skupaj brez DDV:</b></td><td style='text-align:right;'>550,97 €</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align:left;'><b>Osnova za DDV</b></td><td style='text-align:right;'>550,97 €</td>
</tr>
<tr style='border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='text-align:left;'><b>DDV:</b></td><td style='text-align:right;'>109,82 €</td>
</tr>
</table>
<label style='position:absolute;right:80px;bottom:20px;'><b>SKUPAJ:</b></label>
<label style='position:absolute;right:0;bottom:20px;'><b>660,79 €</b></label>
</div></div><br/><br/><br/>

<div style='page-break-inside:avoid;vertical-align:bottom;'>
<font face="Verdana"  >
<br>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:900px;">
          <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td style="width:500px">
     BLAGO DOSTAVIL:&nbsp;______________________<br/><br/>
     Podpis<br/><br/>
     Datum:&nbsp;______________________
    </td>
    <td>
     BLAGO PREVZEL:&nbsp;______________________<br/><br/>
     Podpis<br/><br/>
     Datum:&nbsp;______________________
    </td>
    
   </tr>
<tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center; font-size: 10px;">
                    <i>
                        testting d.o.o., testing, ID za DDV: testing, matična št.: testing
                        <br>
                        tel: +386 XXXXXXXXXX, fax: +386 1 XXXXXXXXX, e-mail: info@XXXX.si, web: www.xxxxxxx.si
                        <br>
                        Družba je vpisana pri okrožnem sodišču v Ljubljani, št. vpisa v registru: 1/XXXXX/00, ustanovni kapital: XX.000 EUR
                        <br>
                        Račun odprt pri NLB d.d., Iban: SIXXXXXXX, SWIFT-BIC: LJBASI2X
                    </i>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
        </table>
</font>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem with fixed position is that it overlaps with other elements. It doesn't move from the first page, it stays fixed.

Comment: @FrenkyB Try changing `fixed` to `absolute`.

Comment: It's the same. Both are out of page flow and thus overlapping with other relative elements.

Answer (score 4):

I used JS for solving your problem and make minor changes in your code. You can look at it, I marked my changes with <--EDIT--> comment.

I assumed, that your problem occur when either of your 'Type of goods' table or 'DDV' table get too high to fit on one page with your 'signature' section.

My JS script use function to check height of those tables, make calculation, and if combined height is bigger than certain treshold (825px) it manualy break page. After that, it set margin for your 'signature' section to move it at the bottom of new page (margin wary from 1110px for EDGE&FFOX to 1160 for CHROME).

Note, that this changes will take effect only for "print" version (i used separate <.style> for @media print) and are not visible in web wersion.

I hope you will find it usefull.

CODE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<!--EDIT-->
<!--you can test different height setups for #tblArticles to see how it behaves /more than 825 will triger page break ;-)  -->
<style>
#tblArticles{font-size: 12px !important; font-family: verdana, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
#tblArticles td{border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;}
#tblArticles th {border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;background-color: #dddddd;}

#tblLeft{position:absolute;left:0; font-size: 10px !important; font-family: verdana, sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse; width:40%;}
#tblLeft td{font-size: 10px !important; border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;}
#tblLeft th {font-size: 10px !important; border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;padding: 8px;background-color: #dddddd;}
#tblRight{position:absolute;right:0; font-size: 10px !important; font-family: verdana, sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse; width:20%;}
#tblRight td{font-size: 10px !important; text-align: center;padding: 8px;}
</style>


<!--container for js function fun() to put new css rule for print if condition is met (see <script> at the bottom)-->
<style id="printStyle"><!--EDIT-->
</style><!--EDIT-->

</head>


<!-- run function fun() after page is loaded and table height is calculated -->
<body onload="fun()"><!--EDIT-->


<table id='tblArticles'>
<thead>
<th>Vrsta blaga/storitve</th>
                                <th>Interna številka</th>
                                <th>Prodana koda</th>
                                <th>Količina</th>
                                <th>EnM</th>
                                <th>Cena brez DDV</th>
                                <th>Vrednost brez DDV</th>
                                <th>DDV</th>
                                <th>Znesek DDV</th>
                                <th>Vrednost z DDV</th>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
<tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
<tr style='visibility:hidden;'><td></td></tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody style='page-break-inside:avoid;'>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td rowspan='1' style='page-break-inside:avoid;'><label>Večerja na zajli</label></td>
<td style=''>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/VzlSSlNYVlo=.jpg><br/>
<label>VzlSSlNYVlo=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style=''><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>1,00</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>KOM</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>91,14 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>91,14 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>9,50 %</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>8,66 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='1'>99,80 €</td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td rowspan='7' style='page-break-inside:avoid;'><label>Veliki kuharski mojster</label></td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/TDZKVzRDVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>TDZKVzRDVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>7,00</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>KOM</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>65,69 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>459,83 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>22,00 %</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>101,16 €</td>
<td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;' rowspan='7'>560,99 €</td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/Q0U2RURCVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>Q0U2RURCVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/RFg0TVZXVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>RFg0TVZXVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/OFdGRTJLVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>OFdGRTJLVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/QlROR0NMVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>QlROR0NMVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/SjNYWkJOVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>SjNYWkJOVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style='border-bottom-style:hidden;'><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr style='page-break-inside:avoid;border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style=''>
<img src=http://localhost:53358/resources/Images/EAN128/M0RFWURXVks=.jpg><br/>
<label>M0RFWURXVks=</label><br/>
</td>
<td style=''><input type='checkbox'><br/><label></label><br/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table><br/>

<!--i marked this element with ID = middleSection (for script)-->
<div id="middleSection" style='page-break-inside:avoid;margin-bottom: 30px;'><!--EDIT-->
<label style='position:relative;left:0;font-size:12px;'>Specifikacija obračunanega davka, dokumenta št.:</label><br/>
<div id='divBottom' style='position:relative;width:100%;min-height:160px;'>
<table id='tblLeft'>
<th>Stopnja</th><th>Osnova za DDV</th><th>Znesek DDV</th><th>Vrednost z DDV</th>
<tr>
<td>9,5 %</td><td>91,14 €</td><td>8,66 €</td><td>99,80 €</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>22 %</td><td>459,83 €</td><td>101,16 €</td><td>560,99 €</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id='tblRight'>
<tr style='border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='text-align:left;'><b>Skupaj brez DDV:</b></td><td style='text-align:right;'>550,97 €</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align:left;'><b>Osnova za DDV</b></td><td style='text-align:right;'>550,97 €</td>
</tr>
<tr style='border-bottom:1px solid black !important;'>
<td style='text-align:left;'><b>DDV:</b></td><td style='text-align:right;'>109,82 €</td>
</tr>
</table>
<label style='position:absolute;right:80px;bottom:20px;'><b>SKUPAJ:</b></label>
<label style='position:absolute;right:0;bottom:20px;'><b>660,79 €</b></label>
</div></div><br/><br/><br/>


<!--i added this to manualy break page when needed by script-->
<div id="break" style="line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</div><!--EDIT-->

<!--i marked this element with ID = bottomSection (for script)-->
<div id="bottomSection" style='page-break-inside:avoid;'><!--EDIT-->

<font face="Verdana"  >
<br>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:900px;">
          <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td style="width:500px">
     BLAGO DOSTAVIL:&nbsp;______________________<br/><br/>
     Podpis<br/><br/>
     Datum:&nbsp;______________________
    </td>
    <td>
     BLAGO PREVZEL:&nbsp;______________________<br/><br/>
     Podpis<br/><br/>
     Datum:&nbsp;______________________
    </td>
    
   </tr>
    </tbody>
        </table>
</font>
<font face="Verdana" size="1"  >
<br /><br />
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:900px;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:center">
    <i>
     testting d.o.o., testing, ID za DDV: testing, matična št.: testing
     <br>
     tel: +386 XXXXXXXXXX, fax: +386 1 XXXXXXXXX, e-mail: info@XXXX.si, web: www.xxxxxxx.si
     <br>
     Družba je vpisana pri okrožnem sodišču v Ljubljani, št. vpisa v registru: 1/XXXXX/00, ustanovni kapital: XX.000 EUR
     <br>
     Račun odprt pri NLB d.d., Iban: SIXXXXXXX, SWIFT-BIC: LJBASI2X
    </i>
              </td>
            </tr>

   </tbody>
        </table>
</font> 
</div>


</body>

<!--script-->
<!--EDIT-->
<script>
function fun()
{ 
 var x = document.getElementById("tblArticles").scrollHeight; //825max for A3 / A4 /A5
 var y = document.getElementById("middleSection").scrollHeight; //have 180px, but I suppose it height can wary - in dependcy on number of 'Stopnja' of 'DDV' you have in Slovenia?   
 var z = document.getElementById("bottomSection").scrollHeight; //have 224px, will not change, i suppose.
 
 if ( x+y > 825 ) //if tblArticles height + middleSection height > 825px, break page and move your bottom section to be aligned (i am using margin-top for that) at the bottom of a new page. 
 {
  //USE:
  //1160px for EDGE & FIREFOX
  //1110px for CHROME
  //SAFARI & IE11 not tested, you must figure out..  ;-)
  //It is possible to write a function for detection which browser is being used, but if only specific browser will be used in your use case, then there is no need for that.
  document.getElementById("printStyle").innerHTML="@media print {#break {page-break-before:always;} #bottomSection {margin:1110px 0px 0px 0px;} }"
 }
}
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Will this work correctly if print is on five pages? (for each page separately)

Answer (score 3):

I used JavaScript to measure page height then decide to assign a transparent image height. So if the total page height is less than 1000px, then height of transparent image is zero and `page-break-before:avoid` are assumed, if the height of page is more than 1000px, height of transparent image will be 800px and `page-break-before:always`. So the section you want, goes to the bottom of next page. Below are changes into your code:

add `#breakerdiv { page-break-before:always;}` to `<style>`.

Define `<div id="calc">` around above table, I mean `<table id='tblArticles'>`.

Change `<div style='page-break-inside:avoid;vertical-align:bottom;'>` to `<div id="breakerdiv">`.

Add

```
<img id="breaker" src="transparent-image.png" style="height: 10px; width: 400px;
position: relative;">
```

just after `<div id="breakerdiv">`. Use one transparent image on your own.

And add this `<script>` before `</body>`

```
<script>

var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );

  if(height < 1000){document.getElementById("breaker").style.height="0";
                    document.getElementById("breakerdiv").style.pageBreakBefore="auto"};

  if(height > 1000){document.getElementById("breaker").style.height="800px"};

</script>
```

I assumed your options are just one or two sheet. Rather than that, you should modify `<script>` for other heights.

Comment: @FrankyB Also [this sample page](http://www.21tech.ir/stackoverflow/1/1.html) updated.

Comment: Will this work if print is on several pages, let's say on five pages? (for each page separately)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want that part stays at the same page, probably there is no room for that, you should try resizing elements. But if you want that part to be at bottom of next page: 
Change this part:

```
<div style='page-break-inside:avoid;vertical-align:bottom;'>
```

to:

```
<div style="page-break-before: always; vertical-align: bottom;">
```

If `vertical-align` doesn't work on all the browsers, try some `margin-top`.

Comment: With this code section is always on the blank page, but it's not aligned to the bottom.

Comment: @FrenkyB Print [this sample page](http://www.21tech.ir/stackoverflow/1/1.html) I've created. Is this what you want?

Comment: Not exactly - bottom section is always on blank (last) page and it's not on the bottom. If there are only a couple of rows in the table this section has enough place to stay on the first page.